# Erro a referenciar Struct com Ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, alocação

Eu estou tentando converter esse algoritmo  abaixo em linguagem c mas eu tendo problemas a fazer chamada da variável e atribuir um valor a **p.chave=1** da struct elemento.

Codigo de Erro:

**error: request for member 'chave' in something not a structure or union**

**Algoritmo**

```
Programa Ponteiro_L5_EX01;
Tipo
Ponteiro = ^Elemento;
Elemento = Registro
           chave : Inteiro;
           Prox  : Ponteiro
           fim;
Var p,prim,h,q  : Ponteiro
    i           : Inteiro

Início
prim <- nil;
aloque(p);
h <- p;
p^.chave <- 1; //ERRO

para i de 1 até 3 faça
  início
     aloque(p);
     q^.chave <- p^.chave+2;
     imprima(h^.chave,p^.chave,q^.chave);
     p <- q;
   fim;
fim-para;
imprima(h^.chave,p^.chave;q^.chave);
fim.
```

**Código em C**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct elemento *ponteiro;

struct elemento
{
    int chave;
    ponteiro prox;
};



main()
{
ponteiro p,prim,h,q;
int i;

prim=NULL;
p=(struct ponteiro * )malloc(sizeof(ponteiro));
h=p;
p.chave=1; //ERRO

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   q=(struct ponteiro *)malloc(sizeof(ponteiro));
   q.chave=p.chave+2;
   printf("%d %d %d",h.chave, p.chave, q.chave);
   p=q;
}

printf("%d %d %d",h.chave,p.chave,q.chave);


}
```

Comment: Geralmente é melhor entender o problema e resolver na linguagem que deseja, sem tentar converter algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem várias coisas erradas, que provavelmente surgem de confusões sobre alguns conceitos. Comecemos pelo erro:

```
p.chave=1; //ERRO
```

`p` é um ponteiro, logo `p.chave` é invalido. Primeiro tem que aceder ao valor apontado por `p` e só depois ao campo:

```
(*p).chave = 1;
```

Se quiser utilizar notação simples e comum pode em vez disto escrever:

```
p->chave = 1;
```

Que tem o mesmo significado.

Seria válido se tivesse o objeto declarado diretamente algo como:

```
struct elemento p;
p.chave = 1;
```

Este erro propaga-se por todos os `.chave` que tem pelo programa fora.

---

A declaração de `p` também está errada:

```
p=(struct ponteiro * )malloc(sizeof(ponteiro));
```

Isto já tem a ver com o `typedef` definido antes que cria um *alias* para um tipo que é um ponteiro e que quase sempre é fonte de problemas, por não tornar esse pormenor evidente, que foi o que aconteceu aqui. O tipo a alocar é `struct elemento` e o `ponteiro` definido no `typedef` não é um sinonimo pois tem precisamente o `*`. Isto faz com que seja errado tanto o *cast* como o `sizeof`:

```
p=(struct ponteiro * )malloc(sizeof(ponteiro));    
//    ^-----^--------------------------^------ ambos errados
```

Correto seria:

```
p = (struct elemento*) malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
```

Ou se quiser usar o `typedef`:

```
p= (ponteiro) malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
```

Este erro também se aplica ao outro `malloc` feito mais abaixo.

Aconselho a perceber bem como funcionam os ponteiros e alocações e todo o tipo de conceitos associados antes sequer de começar a tentar fazer uma conversão.

**Edit**:

Código completo corrigido de acordo com os erros apontados na resposta:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct elemento *ponteiro;

struct elemento {
    int chave;
    ponteiro prox;
};



main() {
    ponteiro p,prim,h,q;
    int i;

    prim=NULL;
    p=(ponteiro)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
    h=p;

    //as duas versões para ver como ambas funcionam
    p->chave=1; 
    (*p).chave = 1;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        q=(ponteiro)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
        q->chave=p->chave+2;
        printf("%d %d %d",h->chave, p->chave, q->chave);
        p=q;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d",h->chave,p->chave,q->chave);
}
```

[Veja como compila no Ideone](https://ideone.com/jYN3EW)

**Agora atenção que compilar e executar é diferente de fazer o que você quer que o programa faça, que nem eu sei exatamente o que é**.

Comment: @FZero É porque não fez as trocas apropriadamente. Já inclui na resposta como fica o código após as correções que eu indiquei para ser mais fácil de perceber.

Comment: Valeu cara salvou a minha vida agora, pois agora posso tentar terminar de fazer a lista desse tipo ai.

Comment: tem alguma indicação de algum material para que eu possa aprende de iniciante a profissional sobre ponteiros e alocação dinâmica pois ainda tenho muita dificuldade de compreender esse dois assuntos

Comment: @FZero Ainda bem que ajudou :). No entanto, sugiro que siga o que eu indiquei e tente aprofundar sobre ponteiros e toda a matéria relacionada pois não só evita problemas deste genero, como também lhe dá uma maior compreensão sobre o código como um todo. Em relação a material no C em geral a própria [wiki do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) tem já varias boas recomendações.